# React hooks in Gatsby: Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-hooks

Trying to implement a custom hook from a react example: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state, but I get the following error:

ERROR:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

The error happen on `useEffect` when I try to import it as a custom hook `usePrevious`.

I tried following:
verified that react-dom and react is on the same version
`react-dom@16.8.5` `react@16.8.5`

Verfied I only have one version of React

Also I do belive the code is not breaking any rules of hooks.

Also tried looking at related issues here on stackoverflow.

CODE:

```
// file: use-previous.js

import { useRef, useEffect} from "React"

export const usePrevious = (value) =>  {

    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });




    return ref.current;
}
```

```
// file: layout.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

import Header from "./header/header"

import { useFacetsData } from "../hooks/use-facets-data"
import { usePrevious } from "../hooks/use-previous"


export default ({ children, ...props }) => {

    const [ searchValue, setSearchValue ] = useState("")

    const [ facetsSelected, setFacetsSelected ] = useState([])

    const facets = useFacetsData()


    const oldSearchValue = usePrevious(searchValue)
    // const oldFacetsSelected = usePrevious(facetsSelected)

    useEffect(() => {
        // if new searchvalue or new facetvalue

        // if (searchValue !== oldSearchValue || facetsSelected !== oldFacetsSelected) makeSearch()
    }) 

    function makeSearch() {
        console.log('make search')

        // move to searchpage 
    }

    function handleSearchChange(search) {
        setSearchValue(search)
    }

    function handleFacetChange(facets) {
        setFacetsSelected(facets)
    }   

    return   (
        <div>
            {/* Main sticky header */}
            <Header 
                facets={ facets } 
                onSearchChange={ handleSearchChange } 
                onFacetChange={ handleFacetChange } >
            </Header>

            {/* route content */}
           {React.cloneElement(children, { facets })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't putting the values in question to useEffect's dependency array serve the same purpose? As in `useEffect(() => ... , [searchValue, facetsSelected])`. React diffs the values in the array automatically and if a change was detected, effect code would run.

Comment: @Powell_v2 very new to hooks so that is very possible, I will have a check. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @Powell_v2 you are correct, for anyone else interested in what Powell_2 was referring to this is the documentation for it: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import in `usePrevious` hooks file is incorrect. `useRef` and `useEffect`  should be import from `'react'` and not `React`;

```
import { useRef, useEffect} from "react"
```